# Index was outside the bounds of the array when parsing csv files

Tags: vb.net, parsing, csv

```
Do While inputstream.Peek <> -1
    newstr = inputstream.ReadLine().Split(",")
    item1 = newstr(0)
    item2 = newstr(1)
    item3 = newstr(2)
    item4 = newstr(3)
    item20 = newstr(19)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(item1)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(item2)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(item3)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(item4)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Item(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(item20)
Loop
inputstream.Close()
```

I'm getting an index out of bounds error, the CSV file is a winamp library. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: meant to tag it as vb.net, 2.25am lol ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing one of your song titles contains a comma. There is no CSV standard, but this site comes close: [creativyst](http://www.creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm).

Often elements that contain commas are surrounded with inverted commas (ASCII character 34 in decimal).

Answer (score 0):

This is just another guess, but perhaps one of your song or album titles contains a newline. I doubt an extra comma would result in an index out of bounds exception (as you would end up with MORE "columns", not less), but an unexpected newline certainly would. You need to make sure that text between quotation marks is treated as a single column otherwise you will have serious issues.

I would recommend using a parser rather than trying to split the file yourself. If you are using VB.NET, then I'd think that the JET OLE DB should be available to you.

See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27802/Using-OleDb-to-Import-Text-Files-tab-CSV-custom

Comment: seemed like too much hassle, i exported it to xml instead then read it with php, i had a choice of vb.net and php.  thanks